# How to avoid hard coding Id into a class?

Tags: apex, seealldata

I am running my test class but keep getting thrown this error

INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY

I have even added seealldata=true to try overcome this but want a more clean solution my class is as follow:

```
global class EmailToLeadWilmslow implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {

 /**
 * Handling Inbound Email
 * @param Messaging.InboundEmail Email object
 * @param Messaging.InboundEnvelope Email enveloppe
 * @return Messaging.InboundEmailResult
 * @access global
 */
 global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email, Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope) {

 Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailresult();

 Lead lead = new Lead();
 lead.FirstName = email.fromname.substring(0, email.fromname.indexOf(' '));
 lead.LastName = email.fromname.substring(email.fromname.indexOf(' '));
 lead.Description = email.plainTextBody;
 String textBody = email.plainTextBody;
 String companyName;
 Integer startPos = textBody.indexOf('CompanyName:');
 if (textBody.indexOf('CompanyName:') > -1) {
 Integer endPos = textBody.indexOf('.', textBody.indexOf('CompanyName:'));
 companyName = textBody.substring(startPos + 'CompanyName:'.length(), endPos);
 }
 lead.Company = companyName != NULL ? companyName : '(not provided)';
 lead.LeadSource = 'Rightmove - Canford';
 lead.Status = 'New';
 upsert lead;
 CampaignMember cm = new CampaignMember(campaignId='7010J000001RUj5', LeadId=lead.Id);
 upsert cm;



 LeadService.executeAssignmentAsync(new Set<Id>{lead.Id});

 return result;

 }

}
```

And my test class is like so:

```
    @isTest (SeeAllData=true)
private class EmailToLeadTest {

  @isTest (SeeAllData=true)
  static private void it_should_execute_assignment_rules()
  {

      Messaging.InboundEmail email = new Messaging.InboundEmail();
      Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope = new  Messaging.InboundEnvelope();

      //Create the email body
      email.plainTextBody = 'This should become a note';
      email.fromAddress = 'test@test.com';
      email.fromName = 'John Doe';
      String contactEmail = 'jsmith@salesforce.com';
      email.subject = 'Dummy Account Name 123';

      //create instance of class
      EmailToLead e = new EmailToLead();
      EmailToLeadCanford eCa = new EmailToLeadCanford();
      EmailToLeadWilmslow eW = new EmailToLeadWilmslow();

    campaign c = new campaign(Name='test');
    insert c;
    Lead l = new Lead(
      FirstName = 'John',
      LastName = 'Doe',
      Description = 'Test Description',
      LeadSource = 'Rightmove',
      Status = 'New'
    );
    upsert l;
    campaignmember cm = new campaignmember(campaignId=c.id, leadId=l.Id);
    upsert cm;
    Test.startTest();
    Messaging.InboundEmailResult resultE = e.handleInboundEmail(email, envelope);
    Messaging.InboundEmailResult resultEw = eW.handleInboundEmail(email, envelope);
    Messaging.InboundEmailResult resultEca = eCa.handleInboundEmail(email, envelope);
    LeadService.executeAssignmentAsync(new Set<Id>{l.Id});
    Test.stopTest();

    System.assert (resultE.success, 'InboundEmailResult returned a failure message');
    System.assert (resultEw.success, 'InboundEmailResult returned a failure message');
    System.assert (resultEca.success, 'InboundEmailResult returned a failure message');

    // Since allTest is disabled, it is impossible to execute Assignment Rules.
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CampaignMember cm = new CampaignMember(campaignId='7010J000001RUj5', LeadId=lead.Id);
```

In the line above you reference a specific campaignID in your email handler class. Your test class can't insert that same `campaign`. That would seem to be the source of your INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY error message. You'll want to import that Campaign in a CSV file into your Test class using `test.loaddata()`.

That having been said, I'd recommend that you move that campaignID into a Custom Setting of some kind so your class will have more reusability. That will also allow you to set a new value for it in your test class eliminating the need to load the CSV file.

Comment: I think the proper solution is to *query* for the `Campaign` instead. The production code *should* change to remove the hard-coded Id.

Comment: @AdrianLarson. I was referring to his production code in the last paragraph of my answer when I recommended to move the campaignID into a Custom Setting for reusability of his code. I don't disagree that querying for the campaign Id would be another means of doing this too, but it appears he's only looking to do this with a single campaign.